# Vertical center a <b> element inside a div

Tags: css

How to vertical center the  tag **names** which are inside the div.

```
<div id="playerlist">
    <div class="opponents_list"><b id="opponent_list_bold_name">bob</b>
    </div>
    <div class="opponents_list"><b id="opponent_list_bold_name">harri</b>
    </div>
    <div class="opponents_list"><b id="opponent_list_bold_name">harri2</b>
    </div>
    <div class="opponents_list"><b id="opponent_list_bold_name">kaleeem</b>
    </div>
    <div class="opponents_list"><b id="opponent_list_bold_name">nehaaa</b>
    </div>
    <div class="opponents_list"><b id="opponent_list_bold_name">nitiisha</b>
    </div>
    <div class="opponents_list"><b id="opponent_list_bold_name">rangi</b>
    </div>
    <div class="opponents_list"><b id="opponent_list_bold_name">tom</b>
    </div>
</div>

.opponents_list {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 3em;
    margin: 0.1em auto;
    background: #666;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.opponent_list_bold_name {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

The fiddle for the above code is at http://jsfiddle.net/cvsn8cu8/. Using the css propery **vertical-align:middle;** did not work

Comment: FYI IDs **must** be unique. Try a class instead.

Comment: Also, if you use ID, you can't target it with a . (class).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the same ID instead of a class. The use the same line height as height

```css
.opponents_list {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 3em;
  margin: 0.1em auto;
  background: #666;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.opponent_list_bold_name {
  line-height: 3em;
}
```

```html
<div id="playerlist">
  <div class="opponents_list"><b class="opponent_list_bold_name">bob</b>
  </div>
  <div class="opponents_list"><b class="opponent_list_bold_name">harri</b>
  </div>
  <div class="opponents_list"><b class="opponent_list_bold_name">harri2</b>
  </div>
  <div class="opponents_list"><b class="opponent_list_bold_name">kaleeem</b>
  </div>
  <div class="opponents_list"><b class="opponent_list_bold_name">nehaaa</b>
  </div>
  <div class="opponents_list"><b class="opponent_list_bold_name">nitiisha</b>
  </div>
  <div class="opponents_list"><b class="opponent_list_bold_name">rangi</b>
  </div>
  <div class="opponents_list"><b class="opponent_list_bold_name">tom</b>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Alternative Option**

You can set the parent to `display:table` and the `b` to `display:table-cell` then vertically align

[**Jfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5jqn306z/)

Comment: Note that this method won't work if the text spans more than one line.

Comment: True but then we get into `display:table-cell` or absolute positioning which seems a little much.

Comment: I see no issues with a table-cell display.

Comment: @Paulie_D All over the internet everyone tells not to use table. Even the MDN <table> doc page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table recommends not to use table. Is <table> different from "display:table" css property

Comment: Yes, `display:table` **is** different from `table`. In this case, an **actual** table would also make sense. - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Answer (score 1):

```css
    .opponents_list {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 3em;
        margin: 0.1em auto;
        background: #666;
        display: table;
        
    }
    b.opponent_list_bold_name {
        display:table-cell;
        vertical-align:middle;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<div id="playerlist">
    <div class="opponents_list"><b id="opponent_list_bold_name">bob</b>
    </div>
    <div class="opponents_list"><b id="opponent_list_bold_name">harri</b>
    </div>
    <div class="opponents_list"><b id="opponent_list_bold_name">harri2</b>
    </div>
    <div class="opponents_list"><b id="opponent_list_bold_name">kaleeem</b>
    </div>
    <div class="opponents_list"><b id="opponent_list_bold_name">nehaaa</b>
    </div>
    <div class="opponents_list"><b id="opponent_list_bold_name">nitiisha</b>
    </div>
    <div class="opponents_list"><b id="opponent_list_bold_name">rangi</b>
    </div>
    <div class="opponents_list"><b id="opponent_list_bold_name">tom</b>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a `line-height`:

```
.opponents_list {
  /* your code */

  line-height: 3em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mention `ID` must be unique. Use class instead. Also you can use `display: table`:

```css
#playerlist {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.opponents_list {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 3em;
  margin: 0.1em auto;
  background: #666;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-row;
}
.opponent_list_bold_name {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div id="playerlist">
  <div class="opponents_list"><b class="opponent_list_bold_name">bob</b>
  </div>
  <div class="opponents_list"><b class="opponent_list_bold_name">harri</b>
  </div>
  <div class="opponents_list"><b class="opponent_list_bold_name">harri2</b>
  </div>
  <div class="opponents_list"><b class="opponent_list_bold_name">kaleeem</b>
  </div>
  <div class="opponents_list"><b class="opponent_list_bold_name">nehaaa</b>
  </div>
  <div class="opponents_list"><b class="opponent_list_bold_name">nitiisha</b>
  </div>
  <div class="opponents_list"><b class="opponent_list_bold_name">rangi</b>
  </div>
  <div class="opponents_list"><b class="opponent_list_bold_name">tom</b>
  </div>
</div>
```